# XML PropOrder - sort by attribute value

Tags: java, xml, rest, sorting

I got a Java RESTful-project with Jersey 2.5.1 and JAX-RS 2.0. I know it is possible to sort the outcoming XML file by the attribute (as showing below), but is it also possible to sort the outcoming order by value of the attribute?

Here is a shortened example where he sorted by the attribute "name", but I would like an explicit sort depending on the value of the attribute (for example in reverse alphabetical order or with a defined importance). At the moment, the outcoming order of the three parts is completely random.

Can i modify the propOrder one level lower (e.g. first every "name" with a value starting with "d" following by "name"s with a "p") ?

```
@XmlType( propOrder = {"name", "code"})
class FHIR_CodeSystem_parameter {
private ValueString name; 
private ValueString code;
```

Outcome, that perma shuffels:

```
<name value="property"/>
        <part>
            <name value="code"/>
            <valueString value="TBC"/>
        </part>
<name value="designation"/>
        <part>
            <name value="code"/>
            <valueString value="ABC"/>
        </part>
<name value="display"/>
        <part>
            <name value="code"/>
            <valueString value="ABC"/>
        </part>
<code value="A10.2"/>
```

Thanks for any hint.